# Looking to have a code that disappears and becomes solid again but without fading just there and not there

Tags: html, css

I want an item to be displayed and then disappear. It should then reappear later but there should be no gradual fade effect.
The item should disappear and come back on a set interval and this behavior should continue indefinitely.

This is what I have so far. I can't figure out what is broken and not pulling my colors and such either. Any help would be awesome!

```css
.goal-cont {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  animation: opacityOn 600s normal forwards;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.blinking {
  animation: blinkingText 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingText {
  0% {color: #000;}
  50% {color: transparent;}
  99% {color: transparent;}
  100% {color: #000;}
}
```

```html
<div class="blinking" /span>
  <div id='title'></div>
  <div id='goal-bar'>
    <span id='goal-current'>0</span>/<span id='goal-total'>0</span>
  </div>
  <div id='goal-end-date'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I googled your issue and I think I found your answer. Check this site: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001651.htm

Comment: @Nicholas, Posted an answer, that might help you.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, for what you want.

There are few things you want to take care of:

- Decide for how much time text should be shown for?
- For how long should it be not shown?
- If you do not want it to fade, avoid using of `transition` property in CSS.

**Mathematical Calculations:**

Text Appears for: **`5m`**

Text Disappears for: **`20m`**

Total animation duration: **`5m + 20m = 25m`**

**CSS Keyframe Calculations:**

> CSS Animation Keyframes comprises of frames based on percents, here we will have 0% to 100%.

```
25m ---- 100%
05m ----  ?

20% of 100% = 5m of total duration(i.e. 25m)
```

> Time duration's are taken based on assumptions, you can change as per your requirement. Also, replaced duration's from `minutes` to `seconds` for below example, so that we do not need to wait too long while testing the animation.

```css
/*You have not used below class so have put into a comment*/
/*
.goal-cont {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  animation: opacityOn 600s normal forwards;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
*/

.blinking {
  animation: blinkingText 25s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingText {
  0% {color: #000;}
  20% {color: #000;}
  20.01% {color: transparent;}
  99.99% {color: transparent;}
  100% {color: #000;}
}
```

```html
<div class="blinking" /span>
  <div id='title'></div>
  <div id='goal-bar'>
    <span id='goal-current'>0</span>/<span id='goal-total'>0</span>
  </div>
  <div id='goal-end-date'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you somehow.